# Excel: Count top % values excluding "0" zeros from range

Tags: excel, function, percentile

I have this formula:

```
  =COUNTIFS(G2:G219,">"&PERCENTILE.EXC(G2:G219,0.9),G2:G219,">0")
```

In G2:G219 I have a list of random numbers (including zeros). I would like to count how many of these numbers are in top 10% percintile, excluding those that are 0.

The additional criteria that I've added `G2:G219,">0"` ,is not working. Any other ideas? 
filtering out and "0" and copying to another place is not a great option,as I have multiple columns and need zeros for other formulas.

Answer (score 0):

```
  =COUNTIFS(G2:G219,">"&PERCENTILE.EXC(G2:G219,0.9),G2:G219,"<>0")
```

I just changed greater than 0 to not equal to 0. It works with this line I tested:

```
 =COUNTIFS(A1:A10;"<10";A1:A10;"<>0")
```

Looking at range A1 to A10 looking for numbers smaller than 10 but not equal to 0. You can parse your ranges in this one if modifying yours fails.

Comment: <10 is not the same as 10% percentile :). Anyway I've found solution, =COUNTIFS(D54:D472,"=0",C54:C472,">"&PERCENTILE.EXC(IF(C54:C472<>0,C54:C472),0.9))  I've copied different range but the difference is I needed to include the "if" statement inside percentile and then commit with ctrl+shift+enter and it works.

Comment: If I understand OP's question correction, it's not so much the excluding the `0` values from the count that is the issue. It's excluding them from the `percentile.exc()` calculation that is screwing up the counts.

Comment: If you want a **non array** version, assuming Excel 2010 or later you can use `AGGREGATE` function to get the percentile, e.g. `=COUNTIFS(D54:D472,0,C54:C472,">"&AGGREGATE(18,6,1/(1/C54:C472),0.9))`